# "Reverse Search" Search function for in Grails App

Tags: jquery, grails, grails-plugin

I searching for an useful Plugin or Idea for my app for reverse search.

I am not sure if it is he right english Word for it...so let me explain:

I got a list of ingredient in my cooking app.

If i choose to create a new receipt i have to scroll through the whole list of ingredients.

I want to be able to add an Letter to the ingredients list.

For example: "e"

Now my list only contains ingredients with the letter "e" at the beginning...for example "eggs"

Any Idea or hint for me?
(Additional Info: I am using Searchable Plugin for Grails at the moment..maybe this matches my needs?)

Comment: Did somebody understand what i try to achieve? Is reverse search the right word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the term you are looking for is "`AutoComplete`"

A good starting point might be the [RichUI Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GRAILS/RichUI+Plugin) which supports [AutoComplete](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GRAILS/RichUI+Plugin#RichUIPlugin-AutoComplete)

Comment: Yeah you are right. Damm sometimes i add to much complexity to my thoughts.^^  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I looks like RichUI does what you are looking for, but I haven't used it yet.
The way I do it is, I have an action in the controller that returns a JSON result of values for a given string. I call the action using AJAX (JQuery).
If the list isn't dynamic, I just set the list in the gsp view, and use do a search using JQuery.